# jQuery: $.cookie different value than PHP $_COOKIE? (only webkit-browser)

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I use jQuery to update and load search results and the page navigation at the bottom of the page. I have a jQuery slider and several HTML-Forms with checkboxes, for each of those elements I set a cookie (on change), and use `.load()` to load the content from `load_search.php`, which works very well in all browsers.

Now I use the same method to upload the page navigation, and I get very weird results. In the search.php, the jQuery code is:

```
// PAGE NAVIGATION //

$('#page_navigation').on("click", ".page_no_item" , function(event) {
      var id = (event.target.id);
      $.cookie("cur_page_no", id);
      search_results_load();
      page_navigation_load();
      alert($.cookie("cur_page_no")); // -> returns the right cookie value
    });
```

also, I check the value on document ready, to be sure:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
      alert($.cookie("cur_page_no")); // -> also returns the right cookie value
    });
```

In the `.php` file that I load, in no-webkit browsers, `$_COOKIE['cur_page_no']` returns the right value, just in webkit browsers, it always returns 1 (which I put as Standard, if the Cookie is empty or not set). `var_dump()` returns always `string(1) "1"` in webkit browsers.

Note: I have tried to run it not on localhost, but the problem remains. Please also note, that I use the exactly same way to read the other cookies (e.g. for the checkboxes which are checked) and they return the right value.

Any ideas or hints are highly appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!! :)

Comment: are you working on the localhost?

Comment: Can you show how you set the cookie in PHP?

Comment: @Dan Lee: yes, I work on localhost, but as mentioned also tried 127.0.0.1 and even uploaded it to a webserver, still the same problems. Furthermore, the other cookies work fine, set the same way...

Comment: @AtesGoral: I do not set the cookie in PHP, I set the cookie using jQuery and only read the cookie with php in the file I load...

Comment: Sorry I tend to overread the little `Note` thingies :) Could you check in the developers console (`F12`) your `Resources -> Cookies` tab, if it exists in there?

Comment: @DanLee: oh, what is this? (might be a stupid question)... do you mean in the browser (chrome/safari)? btw, I work on a mac... ;)

Comment: That's a *veeery* handy tool for Chrome, under Mac open it with `⌥⌘I`. Try it out ;)

Comment: @Chris OK so how do you set the cookie in JS?

Comment: @AtesGoral: like mentioned ($.cookie("cur_page_no", id);), but thanks to Kristian's post I could solve it... thank you anyway very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i was facing this problem, it appeared that in several instances, there was actually two cookies by the same name. One of them was the php created cookie, the other was the javascript created cookie. In other instances, there was one cookie, but php would not properly output the updated value until a full page reload had occurred.

It was problematic that the loading of a fresh page which caused the cookie's desired "new" value to be read. So one way to deal with php's late cookie update effect is to both use the cookie methods available to it and also just setting `$_COOKIE['yourCookieName'] = $val` as well.

The solution I had to stick with, unfortunately, is to handle a particular cookie either completely with JS or PHP and stick with it, and that was the only way i could get it to never have and read / value update / duplication problems

Comment: well, I have no idea why this occurred only with this cookie, but thank you again Kristian, I managed to solve it! :)